# Designing a generic data class

Tags: c#, .net

I want to popuate a listbox with objects of different types. I display the type (humanized) of the object in the listbox.

I created a class ListBoxView that overrides the ToString method and returns a string according to the type. I create a List of ListBoxView and databind this to the listbox.

```
public class ListBoxView
{
    private object m_value;

    public ListBoxView(Object value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (m_value is Car)
            return "Car";
        else if (m_value is User)
            return "Human";
        else
            return "Not defined: " + m_value.GetType().ToString();
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return m_value; }
        set { m_value = value; }
    }
}
```

Can this better be solved with generics? Since I'm new to generics I'm having difficulties implementing using it.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
The classes like Human and Car are part of a datamodel I can't change. I need to solve this on the user interface side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very short solution, but maybe not the best, is to move the logic from your ToString method to the listBox1_Format event handler.

```
private string FormatForListbox(object m_value)
{
    if (m_value is Car)
        return "Car";
    else if (m_value is User)
        return "Human";
    else
        return "Not defined: " + m_value.GetType().ToString();
}

private void listBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
   e.Value = FormatForListbox(e.ListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think I'd just implement `ToString()` on `Car`, `Human` etc and not bother with this class at all.  Otherwise you'll have to update this class every time you add a new type.

If you're worried about I18n of the type names, then keep this class, but only so you can put the results of `ToString()` through a search on a resource file for the "localised" version of the name.

Comment: the problem is that I can't change to classes. They are part of a datamodel that I shouldn't change

Answer (score 0):

Your solution scales poorly. In particular, look what happens if you want to handle special cases in `ToString` for other types than just `Car` and `User`.

You should follow Neil's advice to put this kind of logic elsewhere, namely in the specific classes – either as the `ToString` method or as a different method altogether (see code). In summary, using generics here won't help.

```
interface IInfoProvider {
    String Info { get; }
}

class User : IInfoProvider {
    …
    public override String Info { get { return "Human"; } }
}

class ListBoxView {
    …
    public override string ToString()
    {
        IInfoProvider infovalue = m_value as IInfoProvider;
        if (infovalue != null)
            return infovalue.Info;
        else
            return "Not defined: " + m_value.GetType().ToString();
    }
}
```